# PHP code file run through shell

Tags: php, shell

I have very heavy PHP code file which create PDF on 200,000 records. The total number of PDF pages will be up to 150,000. I tried via a browser to run my code, but it is not able to do that. I think I have to run it through shell - or can anyone suggest alternative approaches?

Comment: "When you can't solve the problem, manage it." - Robert H. Schuller

Answer (score 4):

If you want the PHP script to call it into the shell then:

```
exec("php path/to/script.php&");
```

otherwise, just do whats in the quotes from the terminal.

Also, check your php.ini file it may be set to timeout after a certain amount of time.  That could be your problem.  If that's the case you may be better off handing it to a program written in a lower-level language such as C or C++ then handing it to PHP later.  You could also increase the timout to a higher value, but if it takes too long it may bog down your server.

If you want to see in your browser when it is done.  Make sure you can get the pid of the process and then create a script to see the status of the process.  When it is done have AJAX load it into the current frame.

#### Update:

Something like this:

```
$pid = exec("nohup $command > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!");
```

where command is what you want to do.

Then some jquery like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
   checkStatus();
});

function checkSatus()
{
   $.get("/path/to/checkStatus.php,{pid: <?php echo $pid;?>},function(){
     if(data.running == 1) alert("PDFS done");
   window.setTimeOut(checkStatus,30000);
}
</script>
```

Then the other checkStatus.php file:

```
<?php
  $pid = $_GET["pid"];
  $isRunning = file_exists( "/proc/$pid" );
  if($isRunning){
    json_encode(Array("running"=>1));
  }
  else
  {
    json_encode(Array("running"=>0));
  }
```

*No guarantees on the code.  It was just quickly put together.

Comment: Travis man, Your solution is attracting me but I am totally wipe out how to implement it

Comment: @Strom man you just need to put what is in script into the HTML where you would check it.  There is a better solution, but I wanted to get $pid from the script.  Just start $pid from where you want to see the return.  Make sure that $command is something like "php /path/to"  Copy the checkStatus.php and then change the URL in the ajax and it should work, assuming I didn't make any syntax errors.  Passing it to C or C++ would be harder and I don't exactly know how to do this, but some research might help.  So see if passing it to shell and still having PHP do it works.

Comment: @StromMan if you  have any specific questions I will try to help, besides that this is as far as I know how to go without actually coding it myself.